# Prove: Every Partition Has A Riemann Sum That Equals To The Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I need to prove the following:
Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $[a,b]$.

Prove that every partition $T:a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ has a Riemann sum: 
$\sigma=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\alpha_i)\Delta x_i$ (when $\alpha_i\in(x_{i-1},x_i)$), and $\sigma = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$.

I started proving with induction:
When $n=1$, you can simply use the Mean Value Theorem, and you get that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=f(c)(b-a)$ for a $c\in(a,b)$, and you can take $c$ into the Riemann sum.

However, I can't find a way to prove that if it is true for $n$, it's true for $n+1$ as well.
Help please!

Thanks.

Comment: Apply your case $n=1$ to all intervals $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$. No induction needed.

Comment: Right! I guess I over complicated things. It's as simple as that! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no induction needed; Using what we proved for $n=1$, we know that for every interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$, $\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i}f(x)dx=f(c_i)(x_{i-1}-x_i)$  for a $c_i\in(x_{i-1},x_i)$. When taking all $c_i, i=1,..,n$ into the Riemann sum you get:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(c_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

Thank you @Dirk for explaining this to me!